# Can I murder my friends to death with poison?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I've got poison bombs equipped as my lethal bomb type, but I'm a little wary using them around my allies, for fear that perhaps the poison would effect them as well.

It seems like my fellow assassins might be immune (seeing as I can generally throw one point blank and not be effected by it), but I'm not 100% sure.  My survivability and theirs is sometimes inconsistent.

What about normal NPC companions, such as people I'm supposed to escort?  Will they die if I throw poison at them?  Not directly, mind you, that would be murder.  I mean if they happen to be within the radius of my poisonous explosive device that was clearly thrown at a nearby hostile.  Clearly.

Comment: I really hope you don't consider me a friend.

Comment: @Wipqozn Perish the thought!  Now, if you wouldn't mind standing over there, next to the guy in shiny armor, I need to run an experiment.  There you go!  This won't hurt a bit.  Maybe.

Comment: Why did we ever get rid of the [murder] tag, again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allied NPC's are completely immune to any attacks you can deal, that includes poisoning.  When I say "allied," that includes hired groups, your assassin disciples and other NPC's that follows you around (or you follow).

Otherwise all other NPC's that you can kill with your blade or other weapons are potential targets for poisoning.  Beware as that includes civilians and if you kill too many, you will desynchronize.

Comment: Note that I don't think it's possible to desync from a single explosion, no matter how many people you take out with it.  I'm pretty sure I've knocked out the better part of a dozen civilians simultaneously before.

Comment: Yeah, the first set of kills are usually free.  :)

Comment: Which essentially makes you a terrorist.  The civilian killing kind.  With no in-game repercussions. Unless there was some obscure byzantine law that says mass murder only counts if you throw "two or more bombs in succession," then +1 to Ubisoft for historical accuracy...